# pagination and filtering on a very large table in postgresql (keyset pagination?)

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a scientific database with currently 4,300,000 records. It's a scientific database, and an API is feeding it. In june 2020, I will probably have about 100,000,000 records.

This is de layout of the table 'output':

```
ID   | sensor_ID    | speed    | velocity | direction
-----------------------------------------------------
1    | 1            | 10       | 1        | up
2    | 2            | 12       | 2        | up
3    | 2            | 11.5     | 1.5      | down
4    | 1            | 9.5      | 0.8      | down
5    | 3            | 11       | 0.75     | up
...
```

BTW, this is dummy data. But output is a table with 5 columns: ID, sensor_ID, speed, velocity and direction.

What I want to achieve is a **decent** pagination and filter method. I want to create a website (in nodejs) where this +4,000,000 records (for now) will be displayed, 10,000 records per page. I also want to be able to filter on sensor_ID, speed, velocity or direction.

For now, I have this query for selecting specific rows:

```
SELECT * FROM output ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10000 // first 10,000 rows

SELECT * FROM output ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET 10000 LIMIT 10000 // next 10,000 rows

...
```

I'm searching for some information/tips about creating a decent pagination method. **For now**, it's still quiet fast the way I do it, but I think it will be a lot slower when we hit +50,000,000 records.

First of all, I found this page: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/. I'm interested in the **keyset** pagination. But to be honest, I have no clue how to start.

What I **think** I must do:

Create an index on the ID-field:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_id ON output USING btree (ID)
```

I also found this page: https://leopard.in.ua/2014/10/11/postgresql-paginattion. When you scroll down to "Improvement #2: The Seek Method", you can see that they dropped the OFFSET-clause, and are using a WHERE-clause. I also see that they are using the **last insert ID** in their query:

```
SELECT * FROM output WHERE ID < <last_insert_id_here> ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10000
```

I do not fully understand this. For the first page, I need the very last insert ID. Then I fetch the 10,000 newest records. But after that, to get the second page, I don't need the very last insert ID, I need the 10,000th last insert ID (I guess).

Can someone give me a good explanation about pagination and filtering in a fast way.

The stuff I'm using:
- postgresql
- pgadmin (for database management)
- node.js (latest version)

Thanks everyone! And have a nice 2020!

**EDIT 1:** I have no clue, but could massiveJS (https://massivejs.org/) be something good to use? And should I use it on ALL queries, or only on the pagination queries?

**EDIT 2:** I THINK I got it figured out a little bit (correct me if I'm wrong).

Let's say I have 100,000 records:

1) Get the last inserted ID

2) Use this last inserted ID to fetch the last 10,000 records

```
SELECT * FROM output WHERE ID < 100000 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10000 // last insert ID is here 100,000 because I have 100,000 records
```

3) Show the 10,000 records but also save the insert ID of the 10,000the record to use in the next query

4) Get the next 10,000 records with the new last insert id

```
SELECT * FROM output WHERE ID < 90000 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10000 // 90,000 is the very last insert id - 10,000
```

5) ...

Is this correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's how I handle this.  For the first page I fetch, I use

```
SELECT id, col, col, col 
  FROM output 
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 10000
```

Then, in my client program (node.js) I capture the `id` value from the last row of the result set.  When I need the next page, I do this.

```
 SELECT id, col, col, col
   FROM output
  WHERE id < my_captured_id_value
  ORDER BY id DESC
```

This exploits the index.  And it works correctly even if you have deleted some rows from the table.

By the way, you probably want a descending index if your first pagination page has the largest ids.  `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_id ON output USING btree (ID DESC)`.

**Pro tip**  `SELECT *` is harmful to performance on large databases. Always list the columns you actually need.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using a "infinite scroll", but I need a "has next page"-variable to know if after the fetch of n results there are more results to fetch or not. If not, the loading-icon has to be hidden. So when I have 100,000 records, and I fetch the first 10,000 records, I need to know if there are any records left (indeed, 90,000 records), but on the 10th page when I fetch the last 10,000 records, there are no records left. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The problem I have is that the last query (when there are no results left in the databse), the query keeps running. Lets say I have 100 records and I fetch 10 records at a time. The last ID from the last query will be 1. But there is no record with ID 0 so ID 1 = the last/first record. The problem is that my query will search for records with ID < 1, but can't find any, and the query keeps running. I just want the query to return "false" or something else like that.

Comment: You say a query with no rows in its result set never finishes running?  That is beyond bizarre! Review the actual query? Run it in an interactive shell?

Comment: My explanation wasn't correct. It didn't run without finishing, but because I had no error "management", I never saw the error, and it seemed like it was still running.

Answer (score 0):

In keyset pagination you should set `WHERE` clause on what you want to set in `ORDER BY` clause , and for `DESC` you should use `<` and vice versa.
For the first page you can use something like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 
FROM db.tbl 
WHERE Col3 LIKE '%search_term%'
ORDER BY Col1 DESC , Col2 ASC
LIMIT 10000
```

and for next page , you should send value of `Col1` and `Col2` from last row of the result to the query like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 
FROM db.tbl 
WHERE Col3 LIKE '%search_term%'
AND ( Col1 < Col1_last_row_value AND Col2 > Col2_last_row_value)
ORDER BY Col1 DESC , Col2 ASC
LIMIT 10000
```

and in the server or client side you should check if your query bring back any result or not , if not that means you are done and the loading-icon of "infinite scroll" has to be hidden

Comment: The AND part written in the second is only correct in special cases.
normally you wound have  (col1<foo OR (col1=FOO and BAR<col2)

Answer (score 0):

> Thank you. I'm using a "infinite scroll", but I need a "has next
> page"-variable to know if after the fetch of n results there are more
> results to fetch or not. If not, the loading-icon has to be hidden. So
> when I have 100,000 records, and I fetch the first 10,000 records, I
> need to know if there are any records left (indeed, 90,000 records),
> but on the 10th page when I fetch the last 10,000 records, there are
> no records left. How can I achieve this?

The first thing that came to my mind is using the `${limit} + 1`
you grab the limit you need plus one if the result count is equal to the `${limit} + 1` then there are more pages to get. Do not return the `limit + 1` result count to the client just the limit i.e. the number of per-page the client asks for.