# Sequelize how to write subquery

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hi guys I'm trying to create keyset pagination in sequelize

Currently I have been working on previous and next button logic, to get previous and next posts in list.

I have been using these two posts for reference:

https://ask.use-the-index-luke.com/questions/205/how-to-query-for-previous-page-with-keyset-pagination
[pagination and filtering on a very large table in postgresql (keyset pagination?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619956/pagination-and-filtering-on-a-very-large-table-in-postgresql-keyset-pagination)

I have a Job model with following fields:

```
 Job.init({
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    company: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT,
    excerpt: DataTypes.TEXT,
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  })
```

I have wrote a query, when clicking the `next button`,
I pass the date from client, and then get the next 3 elements

```
  const page = new Date(); // this is date that is passed as query param
  data = await Job.findAll({
                attributes: ['id', 'title', 'company', 'description', 'createdAt'],
                where: {
                    'createdAt': {
                        [Op.gt]: page,
                    },
                },
                limit: 3,
                order: [['createdAt', 'ASC']]
            });
```

But know I have a problem with `previous button`, I'm trying to execute following query with subquery:

```
const page = new Date();
SELECT id, title
FROM (
  SELECT id, title
  FROM jobs
  WHERE createdAt < page
  ORDER BY createdAt DESC
  LIMIT 3
) AS t
ORDER BY createdAt ASC;
```

But I'm always getting syntax error

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: were you able to construct subquery using sequelize? as I am also struggling with subquery formation.. here is my question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72975758/how-to-write-subquery-along-with-main-query-in-sequelize-orm-in-node-js
it will be really helpful if you can provide any solution for the same